# What does "-e" do inside an expression in Perl?

Tags: perl

I ran into this piece of code:

```
unless(-e $SNMPWALK)
{
    print "snmpwalk is not installed!\n";
    exit 3;
}
```

What is the function of `-e` in this expression?

Comment: If you're going to be using Perl, it's worth getting to grips with the [online documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/). In particular the sections on [functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) and [operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) (and, obviously, the [FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html)).

Comment: @DaveCross Thanks. I don't intend to do too much things with Perl, usually is just to rewrite or adapt some plugins for Nagios. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Still worth knowing where the official documentation is :-)

Comment: For sure!! ;-) Thanx again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's one of the *file test operators*. In this case it tests whether the file whose name is in `$SNMPWALK` ***exists***

It's documented in `perlfunc` under [`perldoc -X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Comment: @LuizdeAndrade welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a moment to take the [tour] and then accept the answer by clicking on the tick-mark on the left.